# Replace img src using str_replace doesnt work

Tags: php, str-replace, ckfinder

Hi I'm trying to modify the src of a image that I uploaded by ckfinder and I want a full path I see other answers here but I dont know why my code doesn't work ,look at it please

```
$html = '<p> <img alt="" src="/deconsultas/javascript/ckfinder/files/images/xxx.jpg"/></p>';
$dato = str_replace("src=&quot/deconsultas/javascript","a",$html);
echo $dato;
```

Where is the error please ?

Comment: In your str_replace you have `&quot` instead of "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this.

```
$html = '<p> <img alt="" src="/deconsultas/javascript/ckfinder/files/images/xxx.jpg"/></p>';
$dato = preg_replace("/\/deconsultas\/javascript/","a",$html);
echo $dato;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! But that's what makes /\/ and this \/ ??

Answer (score 1):

Escape quote with slash

use

> \"

instead of

> &quot

Answer (score 0):

just change `str_replace("src=&quot/deconsultas/javascript","a",$html)` to `str_replace("src=\"/deconsultas/javascript","a",$html)`